# A case od the most vexing parse

Tags: c++, vector, most-vexing-parse

My code keeps giving me error `Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'const bus')` Is this a case of the most vexing parse? if so how to fix it. I am trying to print out objects stored in vector. `std::vector<bus> v = {}` is my vector to contain the object whereas `bus` is my class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class bus{
public:
int carNum, releaseYear;
};
int temp1, temp2;
void print(std::vector<bus> const &input)
{
for (auto it = input.cbegin(); it != input.cend(); it++)
{
    std::cout << *it << ' '<< std::endl;
}
}

int main()
{
bus bus1;
bus1.carNum = 0;
bus1.releaseYear = 0;

bus bus2;
bus2.carNum = 0;
bus2.releaseYear = 0;

// Create a vector containing objects
std::vector<bus> v = {};

// Add two more integers to vector
std::cout<<"enter number"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>temp1;
temp1 = bus1.carNum;
std::cout<<"enter year"<<std::endl;
std::cin>>temp2;
temp2 = bus1.releaseYear;



v.push_back(bus1);

print(v)
```

}

Comment: No, it's not a case of the most vexing parse.

Comment: No vexing parse here. `bus` doesn't have an `operator<<`, that's all. Add that, and you'll be fine.

Comment: @cigien can you please type it out with the snippet where it's supposed to be? I don't exactly get it

Comment: What do you expect `std::cout << *it` to do? Why would you expect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no vexing parse here. You simply need to overload the stream insertion operator for the `bus` type. Since `bus` only has public data members, this can be a non-friend function:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, bus const& b)
{
  stream << "#" << b.carNum << " Year" << b.releaseYear;  
  return stream;
}
```

You can of course, format your output however you want.